# ngrx router Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

i'm trying to use ngrx's router-store

*/module*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ....
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(),
        ...
    ],
    ....
})
```

*/store*

```
import { getSelectors, RouterReducerState } from '@ngrx/router-store'

const selectRouter = createFeatureSelector<RouterReducerState>('router');
const { selectQueryParam } = getSelectors(selectRouter);

export const selectedId = selectQueryParam('id'); //error after subscribing
```

but when I subscribe to any `selectRouter` selectors, like `selectQueryParam`,  I get error

```
Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
```

since my `routerState` object has no `root` property...

[image: screenshot of routerState object without root property]

closest thing i could find on google was https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2153

**any idea how i can fix this and use my route selector?**

Comment: Have you also imported `RouterModule.forRoot(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing minimal state for `RouterState`. This might help

```
import { RouterState, StoreRouterConnectingModule } from '@ngrx/router-store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ routerState: RouterState.Minimal }),
    ...
  ],
  ....
})
```